# CPU utilization on software optimization

Tags: optimization

Trying to optimize a desktop application written in C#, I had a doubt. When measuring software performances, I usually consider a reference machine, run the same operations on different software releases and compare the metrics; in this case, I started checking the time elapsed, as the demand is to speed up the software.

Recently, I got exposed to another perspective, like: since the version XYZ is taking only 40% of the CPU, we release something that takes up to 100%, then if the customers still complain about speed, it's up to them to upgrade their hardware.
I doubt it's a good approach, as a mistuned multithreading or a badly implemented loop may achieve the same result, but I'd like to read some feedback. What do you think about it? Which is in general a good starting point when approaching optimization problems?

Comment: *Shrug*.. Reaching high CPU utilization is one prerequisite for maximizing performance but hardly the only one. It is trivially possible to waste cycles on inefficient algorithms or synchronization overhead while still achieving a high load, at which point you are merely using parallelism to waste power. The real question is what your actual performance targets are and whether or not you have met them.

Comment: @doynax Thanks for your answer. At this point, I'd consider "actual performance targets" metrics like take T seconds on the target machine to do something, or don't exceed a RAM threshold, etc., but not "achieve 100% CPU usage", correct?

Comment: Indeed. CPU usage is _not_ an end in itself, it is at best a hint to guide the optimization effort. All things being equal for two algorithms both completing in K seconds the version wasting the least CPU time in the process is preferable to the end-user. Well, unless they are using their laptop as a lap warmer or relying on the fan noise to scare off burglars..